# How to extend Application User to hold a collection of orders?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to extend Application User (using Code-First) to hold a collection of orders, but I'm getting errors.

My Order class is

```
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetails>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelivered { get; set; }
    public bool IsReturned { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to extend Application user like this

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
    public string TaxAuthority { get; set; }
    public string TaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public bool NewsLetterSubscribe { get; set; } = false;
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public  ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm getting the following errors:

> QCMS.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> QCMS.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>
> IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using two db contexts. The one provided for Individual User Account (when the project is first created) and a second one named "qvModel" that is for all other database classes of my project.

```
public partial class qvModel : DbContext
{
    public qvModel()
        : base("name=qvModel")
    {
    }
    //APPSETTINGS
    public virtual DbSet<AdminLog> AdminLog { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<WebLog> WebLog { get; set; }
    //LANGUAGES
    public virtual DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    
    .
    .
    .
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        
        // Precision attribute for decimals
        Precision.ConfigureModelBuilder(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Language>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Brochures)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Language)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        .
        .
        .

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasMany(c => c.OrderDetails)
            .WithRequired(c => c.Order)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Orders)
            .WithRequired(c => c.User)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your IdentityUserLogin type?

Comment: There are not IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole types on my project. I'm using two different contexts for my database. The first is the one provided with Individual User Accounts Authentication when I created the project and the second is the context for my classes.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that is very simple.
The solution is to inherit from IdentityDbContext like this

```
public class qvModel : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public qvModel()
        : base("name=qvModel")
    {
    }
```

I was also missing the following line from OnModelCreating

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

After these changes, my migration is working and I stopped getting the errors I mentioned.